# Map node js app as direcory in Apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I'd like to serve a node app as a path of my domain, like this: http://example.com/foo will actually serve the node app running on port 8080.

I've looked into ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:8080
ProxypassReverse /foo http://localhost:8080
```

This will serve the index.html of the node app, but I get errors in my console about all the assets:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Resource not found) http://example.com/styles/4742a4e8.main.css
```

I thought the ProxyPassReverse directive would take care of that, but apparently not. I have *very* limited knowledge about apache. Any bright ideas on how to solve this?

Disclaimer: yes, I've looked into many nodejs combined with apache questions here on SO, but none of them address the problem of using a subdirectory in the url

Comment: Your assets must point to `/foo` as well (`example.com/foo/styles/`)

Comment: @jgillich That's what I was afraid of. There are no other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will an Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache help on dynamic content only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654833/will-an-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-apache-help-on-dynamic-content-only)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I truly don't see how this is a duplicate for the one you posted. I'm asking something entirely different (?)